My Python Star has a Hollow Pentagon in the Middle, how do i fix this?
I'm making a program for school but I'm having problems with making a star with the Python turtle. The inside keeps being hollow despite much effort to solve the problem. (I'm using Python 3.12.3)
Here is a code segment:
import turtle as t

def star():
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-100,100)
    t.pendown()
    t.fillcolor('black')
    t.begin_fill()
    for p in range(5):
        t.forward(200)
        t.right(144)
    t.end_fill()

star()

I tried many different ways to solve it, but it never worked. I want the star to be completely filled in instead of having a hollow pentagon in the middle.

I can reproduce your problem, but I can't yet see a way to fix it. I found other code on the internet which claims to get a fully filled star, but it is essentially the same code you show here.

The behavior of self-intersecting polygons in Tkinter/turtle is platform-dependent, and there's no way to change it.  To draw a completely-filled star that works everywhere, you need to use 10 non-intersecting segments, rather than 5 that intersect.

Does this answer your question? Turtle graphics, draw a filled star?

You can also stamp a filled triangle 5 times, pivoting about the center.

I believe you'll need to take a more direct route to drawing the star by only drawing the sides so that it's clear what needs to be filled:
import turtle as t

def star():
    # size of star
    size = 80     
         
    # angle to form star
    angle = 144
    
    #fill
    t.fillcolor("black")
    t.begin_fill()
     
    # form star
    for side in range(5):
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(angle)
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(72 - angle)
         
    # fill color
    t.end_fill()

star()

You may need to tweak the size and angle and whatnot to match your needs, but this should get you in the ballpark.

Good answer, but more or less the same as Filling a star shape with Turtle. We already have a ton of posts on star filling in turtle.
